# Binomial theorem expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

Obtain the first four terms of the expansion of $(1+8x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in ascending powers of $x$. By putting $x=\frac{1}{100}$, obtain the value of $\sqrt{3}$, correct to five decimal places.

Comment: That's a lot of imperatives....

Comment: As hinted at by (the) Lord Shark, you might want to give us some info about what you tried, what you think and what you know about this problem.

Comment: Expanding was not difficult but I can't get the second part of the question which is substituting x=1/100 and obtaining the value of radicle 3

Comment: When adding to the question, always add to the question (using the **edit** link) rather than putting i na comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you expand it and substitute $x =1/100,$ you get an approximation to $\sqrt{1.08}.$  For the remainder of the question, note that $$
\frac{\sqrt{1.08}}{\sqrt3} =\sqrt{\frac{1.08}{3}}=\sqrt{.36}=.6
$$